# If I have a PWA made with flutter, could I use an iOS App Clip to use the NFC functionality (in iOS)?

Tags: ios, flutter, progressive-web-apps, nfc, apple-appclips

I'm building a PWA using flutter and I want to allow iOS users to use NFC without installing the native app.

The idea that just came to my mind is to use an App Clip inside the PWA to open this small NFC functionality, is it possible?